# What would you use a "Future" for in App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, future

In the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/FutureWrapper.html), a FutureWrapper is defined like this:

> FutureWrapper is a simple Future that
>   wraps a parent Future.

What's a Future, why would you need to wrap it and when would you use it in App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [`java.util.concurrent.Future<V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). The linked Javadoc is pretty clear and contains an example. For the lazy, here's a copypaste:

> A `Future` represents the result of an
>   asynchronous computation. Methods are
>   provided to check if the computation
>   is complete, to wait for its
>   completion, and to retrieve the result
>   of the computation. The result can
>   only be retrieved using method `get`
>   when the computation has completed,
>   blocking if necessary until it is
>   ready. Cancellation is performed by
>   the cancel method. Additional methods
>   are provided to determine if the task
>   completed normally or was cancelled.
>   Once a computation has completed, the
>   computation cannot be cancelled. If
>   you would like to use a `Future` for the
>   sake of cancellability but not provide
>   a usable result, you can declare types
>   of the form `Future<?>` and return `null`
>   as a result of the underlying task.
>
> **Sample Usage** (Note that the following
>   classes are all made-up.)
>
> ```
>  interface ArchiveSearcher { String search(String target); }
>  class App {
>    ExecutorService executor = ...
>    ArchiveSearcher searcher = ...
>    void showSearch(final String target)
>        throws InterruptedException {
>      Future<String> future
>        = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
>          public String call() {
>              return searcher.search(target);
>          }});
>      displayOtherThings(); // do other things while searching
>      try {
>        displayText(future.get()); // use future
>      } catch (ExecutionException ex) { cleanup(); return; }
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> The [`FutureTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) class is an
>   implementation of `Future` that
>   implements `Runnable`, and so may be
>   executed by an `Executor`. For example,
>   the above construction with submit
>   could be replaced by:
>
> ```
>  FutureTask<String> future =
>    new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
>      public String call() {
>        return searcher.search(target);
>    }});
>  executor.execute(future);
> ```
>
> Memory consistency effects: Actions
>   taken by the asynchronous computation
>   [happen-before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) actions following the
>   corresponding `Future.get()` in another
>   thread.

The `FutureWrapper` is just a decorator for any parent `Future`.

Comment: Why did GAE provide a wrapper class for this?